# global mqtt object: android

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt

I am working on an android app (on android studio) where I have successfully implemented the paho mqtt library for a single activity. I have now run into the issue for the case where I need to persist my mqtt client across multiple activities.

Will i need to create a new client for each activity (subscribe to the needed topics again) and pass modified data of the old client through intents to update the new client ? [this seems like a really bad method and I am assuming that there's a more simple straightforward solution that I am missing]

Comment: Did you implement your paho mqtt class in a service ?

Comment: @Ozan i have it implemented in a helper class that allows me to implement it with ease my activities not as a service - is using a service the way to go with this issue ?

Comment: see my answer @kshishoo

Comment: pls check my answer as correct answer, if it is worked for you.

Comment: @Ozan your answer did not exactly work for me as I am trying to maintain a single client through my application for both publishing and subscribing. your solution works for when there is a fixed subscription list at the start and that no publishes are made. if i am to swap activities and try to add more subscriptions or make publishes I cannot do so with your suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

On your paho mqtt class, you can send broadcast message to your activities. Here how I used;

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    Log.d("MQTT MESSAGE", "Message arrived: Topic: " + topic + "  Message: " + message);
    broadcastSendAction("mqttMessage", "Topic: " + topic + "  Message: " + message);

}


@Override
public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
    Log.d("MQTT MESSAGE", "Connection SUCCESS.");
    mqttStatus = true;
    broadcastSendAction("mqttConnection", true);
    if (!mqttSubs)
        subscribeTopic(mSharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.regId), SepMessageUtils.DEFAULT_REGID), client);
}
```